# Transfer object data over HTTP, including an image

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I have the following scenario: the user is using a mobile application and can create an object that stores the following data:

Name, which is a string
Address, which is a string
Picture, which is taken using the phone's camera and stored locally as a bitmap image.

The user can choose to store these data in the server backend, which is a WCF web service listening for HTTP requests. I know I can encode the object strings as a JSON object and send to the http service over the air, but I am not sure how to transfer the image to the server? Can you encode it as XML/JSON and send it over along with the strings?

The application is currently a windows phone 8 app written in C#, but the same app will be written for iOS devices in the near future.

Comment: You can use a HTTP request via "mutilpart/form-data" so you can upload the image as a file. Or you can just encode the image to Base64 and upload it as a string

Comment: Create a POCO object that contains 2 properties which are Name(string) and Picture(byte array) now you can populate your POCO with the picture and the name and then send it across to the server. Simple C# code for the above should be easy

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the stream conversion for each image and add the details to a list.

in the client side.

```
Stream stream = (Stream)openDialog.File.OpenRead();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        bmi.SetSource(ms);
                        newRow.Thumbnail = bmi;
                }
```

in your service side

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ImageUploadPath");

                          if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                          {
                              Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                          }

                          filePath = filePath + "\\" + picture.FileName + "." + picture.FileType;

                          if (picture.FileName != string.Empty)
                          {
                              fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                              writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
                              writer.Write(picture.FileStream);
                          }
```